# How do I find/replace in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do I find/replace all the values in one table1.field3 that match another table2.field2, using a loop of of table2.field2 that are like a wild card string Matching in table1.field1

Something like this.

```
    UPDATE productsTable.color
SET x = (
    SET productsTable.Color = colorstable.`name`

WHERE productsTable.ShortDescription LIKE colorstable.%`nameOfColor`%';
)
```

Comment: What??? Please post sample input data and output data. Very difficult to understand your need.

Comment: A loop is rarely needed in SQL, if you construct the query properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achive this without using a loop:

```
UPDATE productsTable, colorstable
  SET productsTable.color = colorstable.name
WHERE productsTable.shortdescription LIKE CONCAT('%',colorstable.name,'%');
```